# SOA BPEL dbAdapter not returning all data

Tags: schema, soa, bpel

I am getting fewer rows via the dbAdapter than I do when I run the query in a query tool.

Are there mistakes that I can make in the schema for the adapter that can cause this? The SQL is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs this -- My problem was cause by the SOA server not agreeing that the mainframe had sent a column with a datatype of "short" .. I fixed my problem by casting the data type to integer in my SQL.

SOA over thinks it once again and you have to hack your way around it.